# Using WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn with MVVM - Binding to Property in ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid, mvvm-light

I'm using the excellent MVVM Light Toolkit.  My ViewModel exposes:

```
public const string CourtCodesTypeCourtPropertyName = "CourtCodesTypeCourt";
private List<CourtType> _courtCodesTypes = new List<CourtType>();
public List<CourtType> CourtCodesTypeCourt
{
    get
    {
        return _courtCodesTypes;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_courtCodesTypes == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        var oldValue = _courtCodesTypes;
        _courtCodesTypes = value;

        // Update bindings and broadcast change using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messenging
        RaisePropertyChanged(CourtCodesTypeCourtPropertyName, oldValue, value, true);
    }
}

public const string CourtCodesPropertyName = "CourtCodes";
private List<Court> _courtCodes = null;
public List<Court> CourtCodes
{
    get
    {
        return _courtCodes;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_courtCodes == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        var oldValue = _courtCodes;
        _courtCodes = value;

        // Update bindings and broadcast change using GalaSoft.Utility.Messenging
        RaisePropertyChanged(CourtCodesPropertyName, oldValue, value, true);
    }
}
```

The View has a DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid
      ItemsSource="{Binding CourtCodes, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
      AlternatingRowBackground="{DynamicResource OffsetBrown}"
      AlternationCount="1" Margin="45,0">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Abbreviation, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         Header="Abbreviation"
         Width="25*" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FullName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         Header="Court"
         Width="75*" />
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="CourtType" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.CourtCodesTypeCourt} TextBinding="{Binding CourtTypeDescription}""/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

The DataGrid has an ItemsSource, as you can see, of CourtCodes.  I want the CourtType column to be a drop down of all enumerated CourtTypes that are contained within CourtCodesTypeCourt.  For the life of me, I can't seem to populate the DataGridComboBoxColumn with anything.  The current failed attempt is looking to use RelativeSource... what am I doing wrong?

In addition to not working, the two errors I see are:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot
>   find source for binding with reference
>   'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
>   AncestorType='System.Windows.Window',
>   AncestorLevel='1''.
>   BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.CourtCodesTypeCourt;
>   DataItem=null; target element is
>   'DataGridComboBoxColumn'
>   (HashCode=38771709); target property
>   is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

and

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 :
>   BindingExpression path error:
>   'CourtCodesTypeCourt' property not
>   found on 'object' ''Court'
>   (HashCode=38141773)'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=CourtCodesTypeCourt.CourtTypeDescription;
>   DataItem='Court' (HashCode=38141773);
>   target element is 'ComboBox'
>   (Name=''); target property is 'Text'
>   (type 'String')

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`DataGrid` column definitions don't participate in the logical tree in the way you would expect. It's ridiculous, but last I checked you have to do something like this:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="CourtType" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Type}">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.CourtCodesTypeCourt}"/>
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.CourtCodesTypeCourt}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

You'll notice I've also changed your `TextBinding` to a `SelectedItemBinding`. I'm not sure if you actually intended a `TextBinding`, but if you just want to allow the user to select between the list, then `SelectedItemBinding` is likely what you want.

Also, your VMs don't exactly follow best practices. You're using `List<T>` instead of `ObservableCollection<T>`, and you're exposing it as `List<T>` rather than something simpler such as `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Kent... this definitely gets me closer.  I agree... it is ridiculous to have to resort to this kind of syntax.  I'm struggling.

I now have the CourtType objects populating the DataGridComboBoxColumn, but within this syntax, how do I control the displayed text?  Currently it lists the type name, not it's CourtTypeDescription property.

Secondly, I appreciate your feedback regarding best practices... I was, perhaps mistakenly, under the impression that the MVVM Light Toolkit made mvvminpc snippet-created properies into ObservableCollections... am I off on that too?

Comment: Ignore the ObservableCollections best practice question... I tested it a bit and see the value.  The ability to hook into the CollectionChanged event seems well worth it on it's own right.

I could use a nudge on the syntax for the DataGridComboBoxColumn... thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Mike: you should just be able to set `DisplayMemberPath="CourtTypeDescription"` on your `DataGridComboBoxColumn`.

Comment: +1 The `RelativeSource` suggestion shown put me on the right track to solve a different issue with DataGrid Style bindings. Many thanks! :)

Comment: be sure to remember to add 'DataContext' to Path (as shown here). I've made this mistake several times

Answer (score 4):

Here I have found answer http://cinch.codeplex.com/discussions/239522

For the DataGridComboBoxColumn you have to create a StaticRecource of the ItemsSource like:

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Element=theView, Path=DataContext.ViewModelCollection1}" x:Key="ViewModelCollection1" />
```

and bind it to the DataGridComboBoxColumn with following:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModelCollection1}}"
```

Thats because the DataGridColumns are not a part of the visual tree.

And if you want to bind on a collection of a item of the DataGrid you have to set the ItemsSource over the two styles:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=ModelCollection1}" />
    </Style> </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle> <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=ModelCollection1}" />
    </Style> </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this brilliant tutorial/example:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Best-ComboBox-Tutorial-5cc27f82