# DataGridComboBoxColumn Dynamic Binding

Tags: wpf, dynamic, binding, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a datagrid with a combobox column. I want to bind this column to a list of items that I generate dynamically in the code-behind file. All rows of the datagrid will have the same list of items in the combobox column. I have done static binding using ObjectDataProvider, but I am not sure how to do this dynamically.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you,
Santosh

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically?

Comment: By dynamically, I mean to create items for the combobox column from a database table. These items should be the same for all rows of the datagrid and must also be available for the user to select when adding a new row to the datagrid. Currently, I am able to provide static data using ObjectDataProvider.

Comment: Check this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562934/using-wpf-datagridcomboboxcolumn-with-mvvm-binding-to-property-in-viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) for your items, if you then bind the `ItemsSource` of the DataGrid to this collection you can dynamically items to the collection and they will also be added to the DataGrid. See the [collections binding section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#binding_to_collections) on MSDN for more info. If this is not what you are looking for you might want to elaborate as your question still seems quite unclear (at least to me).